# Ways of dividing people into groups.

Tags: permutations, combinations

The number of ways of dividing $12$ people into $3$ groups of $4$ each is?
My attempt:First we choose $4$ members in $(12C4)$ ways.And then out of remaining $8$ we choose them in $(8C4)$ ways.Finally the last $4$ members will be in one group. All the events occur simultaneously so the answer is supposed to be $(12C4) \cdot (8C4) \cdot (1)=(12!/(4!)^3)=x$ (let).But the answer given is $x/3!$ .Is there anything wrong in what I did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your answer specified an order to the three groups, whereas the problem did not specify that the groups be in any order.  Thus, you counted each answer $3!$ times, and must account for this in order to get the correct solution.